# Securing a web service from "XML Injection"

Tags: xml, web-services, authentication, code-injection

Currently we have clients that belong many different companies who access our web services. A number of new clients are part of a franchise and want access to company data within the same franchise.

Previously we compared a hash of the company id stored in their authentication credential to the hash of the id of the company they were requesting data for, thus ensuring each company could not request data for another company. However, this method will no longer work as a client may need to access another clients data.

The question is, what is the "best way" to prevent 'XML Injection' (if that's what it is called) where someone could intercept the sent web request and modify the XML with intent to look at a competitors data.

The only method I've come up with so far is to maintain a server side client hierarchy (e.g. Client A/B/C are part of Franchise A) so we know who is part of which franchise and explicitly check before the data is retrieved.

I've noticed many questions on how to secure web service access, this is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two problems.

**Stopping the HTTP request being intercepted and credentials being used by a third party**

> The question is, what is the "best way" to prevent 'XML Injection' (if that's what it is called) where someone could intercept the sent web request and modify the XML with intent to look at a competitors data.

This would be a man-in-the-middle attack.

The solution is simple, use encryption by transferring the data over HTTPS instead of plain HTTP.

**Stopping one client from accessing the data of another client without permission**

> The only method I've come up with so far is to maintain a server side client hierarchy (e.g. Client A/B/C are part of Franchise A) so we know who is part of which franchise and explicitly check before the data is retrieved.

This is a different problem, and that is the correct approach to solve it.

Store a list (or other data structure) of which sets of data can be accessed by each user. On each request, compare the requested data combined with the credentials of the accessing user with the [access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Comment: Thanks for breaking it into two - it simplifies my thinking... we already have HTTPS enable, so we're covered there. It was the second part which was important. I had wondered if there was a less explicit / heavy way of achieving what I required.

Comment: It really depends on the precise nature of the rules regarding whom is allowed to access what data. Complex rules require complex programming to express them. Simple rules require simpler programming.

Comment: The rules are completely arbitrary - it all depends on who is affiliated with who, so I can't think of any rules that wouldn't include maintaining that relationship... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to fit an extra layer of complexity over the "broken" credential check you already have. Fix the credential check instead.

What is the problem? The "credential token" you use to check access is the company id (a hash of it, but it doesn't make any difference).

How to fix it? Simply don't use the company id -- use something better instead.

So for example: when someone authenticates against your web service, don't give them an auth token based on their company id. Give them an auth token of (let's create an abstract entity here) an "access domain". Have each company in your database be mapped in a one-to-many relationship to any number of "access domains".

Whenever someone asks for data, see which access domains include that data (e.g. check what domains the company whose data is requested is in). If the credential token authorizes access to *any* of these domains, go ahead and provide the data.

This is just a basic extension of your current credential infrastructure that will serve your needs while remaining sessionless (I imagine lack of session state is exactly why the system was designed like that in the first place).

Of course note that:

- **This system of access control is not secure against trusted-user attacks.** Unless there are other mechanisms in place, what's to stop a customer from brute-forcing the authentication token they send you until it matches the hash of another company id (or access domain) and they get access to that data?
- As David says, it's also **not secure against man-in-the-middle attacks, or even to passive eavesdropping.** Follow his advice and use HTTPS to expose your services. This is a no-brainer.

Comment: Your correct, our web services are stateless.  The reason I would use a hierarchical structure is that I can traverse up and down the hierarchy (recursively query it in sql and the cache it) depending on what was wanting to be accessed and be able to share hierarchy's amount clients. Using this method of "access domain" wouldn't the be a lot more data to maintain separably?

Comment: @MrShoubs: The "access domain" is clearly a superset of the hierarchy tree, since you can arrange for an access domain to behave exactly like a hierarchy if you populate it with the correct data. I 'm suggesting it so that you don't have to change the system *again* when something comes up that a hierarchy cannot handle.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea, but I'm not clear on how you're suggesting to implement it... Assign each client an access domain, then for each client maintain a list of other access domains it can access (or have a hierarchy of access domains). I think I've missed something as this seems similar to the initial idea of maintaining a hierarchy and explicitly checking (except this method implements the check as part of the auth token).

Comment: @MrShoubs: Assign each client an access domain, and assign each company to any access domains. This way you can give a client access to any number of companies and you are not limited to hierarchical client structures (client 1 has access to A; client 2 to A+B; nothing stopping client 3 from having access to just A+C, as "A+C" is an access domain independent of any other).

Comment: That is a (good) solution to a slight different problem. The reason for hierarchical data is to restrict companies access - cuts down on maintenance - assign a franchise, they automatically gain the access required without any extra admin. (client = company), admin users control internal to the company who can access what in the client app - we don't care about this). of course, as you say, you are limited to the hierarchical structure, but in this case, there aren't many and you can always create another one if you wanted to group some clients together outside of the franchise.